# Changing textarea font color

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I linked a textarea to a cell. The font color is changing based on the cell value. Unfortunately the textarea font color isn't changing when the linked cell is changed. When I open the textarea and press Enter the color is changing.

Is there a way I can automate this because it's way too much work to press every single textarea and press enter.

Comment: Do you have existing VBA code to set the textarea color based on the value input into the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have linked cell A1 to an ActiveX Text Box on the same sheet.

I want the textbox forecolor to be red if cell A1 = 1, else blue for anything else.

In the textbox code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Range("A1") = 1 Then
        Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = vbRed
    Else
        Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = vbBlue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not changing anything and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Can I check that (a) you are using Active X text box, (b) you have linked the text box to a cell by setting the `LinkedCell` (right click text box > properties), and (c) the VBA code is in the right place  (right click text box > view code), and (d) you haven't renamed the textbox (making `TextBox1_Change()` invalid)?

Comment: Yes, I even made a new Excel document to test it. Doesn't work either

Comment: In which case, I am stumped. It works for me on Excel 2010.